# Errors when trying to save parquet file to a CSV using to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyspark

I am trying to read a parquet file that has some lab data in it, then load that into a temp table, do a query on that table, and then save the results to a CSV file, with columns and comma separated.  Here is my code:

```
lines = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs:////data/lab_01/")
lines.registerTempTable("test_data")
resultsDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from results")

header = ["lab_key", "tray_id", "time", "gene_id", "source"]
pandas.resultsDF.to_csv("/data/results.csv", sep=",", columns = header)
```

The error I get is this, which is on the last line of code:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'resultsDF'

I am looking for a CSV file with headers, like below:

```
lab_key  tray_id   time   gene_id  Source
10       26905972   1     8315     2        
30       26984972   1     8669     2        
30       26949059   1     1023     2        
30      26905972    1     1062     1
```

Here is what my data frame, resultsDF, looks like:

```
[Row(lab_key=1130, tray_id=26984905972, time=1, gene_id=833715, source=2),
 Row(lab_key=1130, tray_id=26984905972, time=1, gene_id=866950, source=2),
 Row(lab_key=1130, tray_id=26984905972, time=1, gene_id=1022843, source=2),
```

Comment: remove pandas. `resultsDF.to_csv("/data/results.csv", sep=",", columns = header)`

Comment: I get an error when doing that:  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this: you need to convert to Pandas like this & convert to csv

```
resultsDF.toPandas().to_csv(" ")
```

This is a bad approach, as theres no need to convert to Pandas DataFrame if the need is just to save as csv, you should use the below method

```
resultsDF.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('path+my.csv',header = 'true')
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not sure about Pandas, but this solution works.  The headers are there too.

Comment: Can you tell my why the 'com.databricks.spark.csv'?  What is that for?

Answer (score 0):

You have Spark dataframe which you need to first convert into pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

lines = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs:////data/lab_01/")
lines.registerTempTable("test_data")
resultsDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from results").toDF()


resDF=pd.DataFrame(resultDF)
header = ["lab_key", "tray_id", "time", "gene_id", "source"]

# removed pandas from below line
resDF.to_csv("/data/results.csv", sep=",", columns = header)
```

Comment: import pandas as pd

lines = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs:////data/lab_01/")
lines.registerTempTable("test_data")
resultsDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from results")

resDF=pd.DataFrame(resultsDF)
header = ["lab_key", "tray_id", "time", "gene_id", "source"]
resDF.to_csv("/data/results.csv", sep=",", columns = header)

Comment: The above    resDF=pd.DataFrame(resultsDF)     gives me an error: ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!   I assume the resDF should be used on the last line.

Comment: OK, do you have other suggestions?

Comment: add `.toDF()` where you fetched the query. See  the edited answer

Comment: Errors occur: 
ParseException: "\nextraneous input '10' expecting {<EOF>, '(', ',', '.', '[', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', ...

Comment: A long list of errors occurred, so it would be a lengthy post if I copy all of them.  have you tried running the sample code on your end?

Comment: can you edit the question and post the traceback? I tried by creating sample dataframe which is working.

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o278.toDF.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (7): lab_key, tray_id, time, gene_id, source
New column names (0):

Comment: I posted part of the trace. I did not modify the code, as it is the same.   This works without the .toDF()                                                              
lines = sqlContext.read.parquet("hdfs:////data/lad_01/")
lines.registerTempTable("test_data")
resultsDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from test_data")
resultsDF.take(10)

Comment: maybe output of `resultsDF.show()` will help me to understand.

Comment: Could be my output that is the difference.  My code looks similar as https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_saving_dataframe_as_csv/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164459/discussion-between-steve-mcaffer-and-akshay-nevrekar).

Comment: resDF=pd.DataFrame(resultsDF)  when running this line, I get:  ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Answer (score 0):

You can you below option:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda line: ",".join[t1 for t1 in line]).saveAsTextFile("filename")

df.rdd.map(lambda line: ",".join(map(str, line) ) ).saveAsTextFile("filename")
```

Let ms know if this helps.